# Is it wrong to use the "==" operator when comparing to an empty list?

Tags: python, list, pycharm, pep8

PyCharm (4.0.6) complains when I do a comparison to an empty list using the `==` operator, but it doesn't when I use the `is` operator:

[image]

I guess this is something related to PEP 8, but the problem is that when I use the `is` operator, as PyCharm suggests, I have a false negative. Here is a simple example in iPython shell to show that in this case the `==` operator seems more appropriate, since the `is` operator returns a false negative:

```
In[2]: actions = []
In[3]: actions == []
Out[3]: True
In[4]: actions is []
Out[4]: False
```

Could someone please explain why PyCharm complains about the `==` operator when comparing to an empty lists? Am I doing something wrong according to PEP 8?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Comment: The `==` isn't *wrong*, it's just suggesting that there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Using the `==` operator seems more explicit, but it would force type differenciation. Since Python is "duck typed", I guess that's why they came with a single solution to check if a sequence is empty. Using `if seq:` works for lists, strings, tuples and dictionaries.

Comment: If anyone finds it useful, I created a youtube tutorial discussing the '==' operator and comparing the different ways to check if list is empty https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8V88bl3tuBQ

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Quoting [PEP-8's Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) section,

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.
>
> ```
> Yes: if not seq:
>      if seq:
>
> No: if len(seq)
>     if not len(seq)
> ```

Since empty sequences are Falsy in Python,

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool(())
False
```

you can simply use `if not` as mentioned in the PEP-8.

**Note:** You should never use `is` to compare if two values are equal, because `is` operator checks if two objects are one and the same, but `==` checks if two objects are equal.

---

I dug in to the source code to figure out what is happening. When we do `a == []`,

```
>>> dis(compile('if a == []: pass', "string", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 BUILD_LIST               0
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

we are constructing a new list and it would be a very costly operation, just for comparison. On the other hand

```
>>> dis(compile('if not a: pass', "string", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         9
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

we are trying to see if the current sequence could be Truthy. This internally checks if the length of the sequence is zero (which is just a simple lookup, as the length of the list is maintained in a variable). If the length is zero, then `if not actions:` will be Truthy. Here we don't construct a new list, but we are just checking the length implicitly, instead of explicitly doing

```
if len(actions) == 0:
```

So, I am guessing that Python Gurus are suggesting `if not seq` because there could be performance advantage as well.

Comment: But this doesn't seem the "pythonic" way of coding. Explicit comparing with an empty list seems more readable to me. Is it wrong?

Comment: @renatov: I suspect that Guido, Tim, and Barry have a better sense of what's pythonic than you do, but if you disagree, feel free to try to convince the Python community that PEP 8 needs to be changed.

Comment: @abarnert the argument would carry more weight if the example showed exactly what the question asked, which to me is the most straight-forward and natural way to check for an empty list, more so than checking the length.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I think it's pretty clear that the intention is not "`if not seq:` is still bad, but we listed it as "Yes" just to make the point that `if len(seq):` is really bad". But people have been confused by the fact that it doesn't mention `if seq != ''` before, and people probably will be confused again. Maybe PEP 8 should be improved to make the intention clearer.

Comment: @renatov: More importantly, thefourtheye showed you that PEP 8 says that `if not seq:` is a Yes. That's the answer you asked for. If you're not arguing that PEP 8 is wrong, what _are_ you saying? Are you asking for the rationale behind that decision, or for pointers to where it's been discussed? If so, that's a perfectly good question (although not necessarily a good question for SO), but it's not your original question, so asking it as a followup in the comments is not the way to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to PEP8 doc you should use

```
For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.

Yes: if not seq:
     if seq:

No: if len(seq)
    if not len(seq)
```